# Renaming same name Multiple email attachments when Copying from outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Historically I was using Excel and lotus notes to do this, company is transitioning thru to Outlook 2016 as it's standard email client.

We get daily reports to a mailbox from our Fridge units at multiple branches. each branch is a separate email but some of the attachments are named the same.

I used a script that copied the attachments from LN and it had a private function that in the processing of copying the attachments it would rename them if they had the same name.

I found a script here at stack overflow that I modified to save the attachments from Outlook into a Network folder. That works fine.

Here is the script

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String

' Get the path to your My Documents folder
'strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
strFolderpath = "J:\Clayton\Logistics\Plantwatch\REPORTS\ZDumpSites\"
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = strFolderpath '& "\Attachments\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            ' Delete the attachment.
            'objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
            'check for html and use html tags in link
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles

        Next i

        ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        ' Check for HTML body
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
        Else
            objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
        End If
        objMsg.Save
    End If
Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am trying to add this Function to this Script:

```
Private Function UniqueFileName(ByVal Fn As String) As String  ' Rename same Name files.

    Dim Fun As String                     ' Function return value
    Dim Sp() As String                    ' Split file name
    Dim Ext As Long                       ' file extension character count
    Dim i As Integer                      ' file name index

    Sp = Split(Fn, ".")
    If UBound(Sp) Then Ext = Len(Sp(UBound(Sp))) + 1
    Fun = stPath & Fn
    Do While Len(Dir(Fun))
        i = i + 1
        Fun = stPath & Left(Fn, Len(Fn) - Ext) & _
              "(" & CStr(i) & ")" & Right(Fn, Ext)
        If i > 100 Then Exit Do
    Loop
    UniqueFileName = Fun
End Function
```

But search as I can I cannot see where this would fit or be added to the script.

How can I add this function to the excellent Script above to rename same named attachments?

I suspect I am missing something simple!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
```

to:

```
 strFile = MakeUnique(strFolderpath & strFile)
```

Function:

```
Function MakeUnique(fPath As String) As String
    Dim rv As String, fso, fName, fldr, ext, n
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    rv = fPath
    ext = "." & fso.getextensionname(fPath)
    n = 2
    Do While fso.fileexists(rv)
        rv = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - Len(ext)) & "(" & n & ")" & ext
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    MakeUnique = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

add the following to your variables

```
Dim nFileName As String
Dim Ext As String
```

then call the Function

```
        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

            ' ==============================================================

'                ' // added
            Ext = Right(strFile, _
                             Len(strFile) - InStrRev(strFile, Chr(46)))

            nFileName = FileNameUnique(strFolderpath, strFile, Ext)



            '================================================================


            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFolderpath & nFileName ' < added
```

Here are you have two functions

```
'// Check if the file exists
Private Function FileExists(FullName As String) As Boolean
Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If FSO.FileExists(FullName) Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If

    Exit Function
End Function

'// If the same file name exist then add (1)
Private Function FileNameUnique(sPath As String, _
                               FileName As String, _
                               Ext As String) As String
Dim lngF As Long
Dim lngName As Long
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(FileName) - (Len(Ext) + 1)
    FileName = Left(FileName, lngName)

    Do While FileExists(sPath & FileName & Chr(46) & Ext) = True
        FileName = Left(FileName, lngName) & " (" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop

    FileNameUnique = FileName & Chr(46) & Ext

    Exit Function
End Function
```

Good Luck - :-)

Comment: Om3r your solution works brilliantly.  will check the shorter version from Tim to see which is best for my needs!.  Cheers.